# I am trying to make a while loop that has not in it and its not working

Tags: python

```
playerpoint = [2, 2]
#this works with the [5, 2] but not with the other point
while not playerpoint == [5, 2] or not playerpoint == [0, 2]:
space = input("Enter W to go up\nEnter A to go right\nEnter D to go left\nEnter S to go down ")
Move(space)
playerpoint = [5, 2]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Simply showing us a few lines of code with a comment about something "not working", does not constitute a *question*.

Comment: You need to indent code under a while loop if you want it to run

Comment: @OneCricketeer the original code was not posted with code formatting at all; I tried to fix it. I think it's like this.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Please let OP [edit] on their own

Comment: Agreed. I suspect this should probably be a duplicate of one of the various de Morgan's law questions, though.

Answer (score 1):

Think about it: of those two “or” conditions, at least one will always be true. The loop will therefore run forever. Consider whether you mean “and” and not “or”.

Another option — one that’s both more “Pythonic” and easier to read — is to explicitly aloof while the point is a member of a specific set of points (thanks @onecricketeer):

```
while playerpoint not in {[5, 2],  [0, 2]}:
```

Comment: Or consider 
`while playerpoint not in {[5, 2],  [0, 2]}:`

Answer (score 0):

The thing to keep in mind here is that when you add a negation to a condition that's a disjunction (`or`) or a conjunction (`and`) means you have to flip the conjunction to a disjunction, or vice versa - known in logic as DeMorgan's laws:

This is why `not a or not b` is *not* equivalent to `not(a or b)` but rather to `not(a and b)`.

To illustrate with your example: Since the variable `playerpoint` cannot be both `[5, 2]` and `[0, 2]` at the same time, in your condition, one of the two negated conditions will inevitably be true: If `playerpoint` is `[0, 2]`, then it will meet the `not [5, 2]` condition, or vice versa.

Presumably, the condition you want to test is that `playerpoint` is neither of the two. You can test this, under DeMorgan's Laws, as `playerpoint != [5,2] and playerpoint != [0,2]`. The more "Pythonic" way of expressing this would, however, be `not playerpoint in [[5,2], [0,2]]` (which says the same but a bit more succinctly).